# libgdx: how to manage entity classes

Tags: java, game-design, sprites, libgdx, game-mechanics

Good day sirs, I know this is a newbie question but I really need to ask it. I've been reading a lot of sample codes on libgdx, and I have seen entities(player, enemy, boss,etc.).

my question is what should an entity class contain?as I have seen it contains states which i will use to animate my sprite, should I also put my inputs/controls, and animation in this entity class?

Comment: This is pretty vague. It should contain whatever it needs. What does it need? Depends on the game, the developer, the target audience, the budget...

Comment: To clarify, are you using or building an entity/component sytstem?

Comment: @anko oh sorry for the vague question dear sir. I'll try to be more accurate next time that i will ask. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ashes999 I'm trying create a set of entities for my game which are player, enemy,and bosses. since my knowledge in programming is still pretty basic, I was wondering what should a player entity should contain?just a basic guideline would do or is it still to vague?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're struggling with basic object-orientation. There are really two ways you can do this:

1. Use classes. This is tricky, because your `Player` class will have data (player health, etc.) but also the current view to draw (sprites, etc.)  A better way would be option #2
2. Use a component-entity system. [This article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) describes it quite well, as an improvement over option #1; you basically create small components (eg. Sprite, KeyboardInput) and entities (eg. Player) that are a composite of multiple components and "wiring" to make them work together.

If option #2 seems too "hard," try option #1 first. If your game is a small size, it may be "good enough" for you.

Comment: I am trying to use the #2 approach. But my progress is pretty slow, I'm still trying to figure out which is which. I'm reading the article though it is really useful. anyway thanks dear sir. kudos to you.